# Cross Site Request Forgery in web services

Tags: django, security, rest, csrf, django-csrf

So I am working on a project where there is going to be a Security review to ensure that we are keeping certain data safe (student data to be specific). I personally don't need to worry too much about this right now as the plan is "dev now, secure later" so in some sense I am doing "premature security optimization" but I'd like to know anyway.

I'm using django which has some cross site request forgery protection built in. If I enable it  I can't preform file uploads but the solution it gives is to require a crsf_token to be put in a form but I don't actually have a form as this part of the project is a just a service. So I am wondering is it safe to mark this as exempt from CSRF protection?

There are no cookies set, there is no session stored, and every request must be authenticated via a small set of self signed certificates I create and will only be giving to the small set of trusted people (currently 1). It does not seem to me that CSRF applies here so that means I can mark what I need to as exempt from CSRF protection right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the ins and outs of your site but I would say **no, it is not exempt from [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) protection**.

Say your site was `https://www.example.com` and I am assuming the self signed certificates are SSL certificates used from the client side [like this](https://github.com/kimvais/django-ssl-client-auth).

Now say they can interact with your site and as they've installed their client cert in their browser. Now, say one of your users accidentally visits `www.evil.com`. `www.evil.com` has a hidden form that makes a request to your website from your users's browser. This form submits to `https://www.example.com/delete_everything`.

Before your site does anything, it checks the client certificate - hey it is valid so proceeds to do it's stuff.

This is why you need CSRF protection - something within the payload of the submitted form that needs to be first read from your own site (e.g. a token). If `www.evil.com` tries to read this via the user's browser, they cannot as it is protected by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: much better answer! I wasn't thinking about someone installing this in their browser. While I really hope that the people I am trusting with these certificates are not dumb enough to install these in their browsers I feel that I should still protect against this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have many options, lets think someones:

- write a middleware to act before CsrfViewMiddleware and do some validations (source ip, header, token, etc)
- decorate with @csrf_excepmt and do the validations inside the view function

Comment: If I preform the validations mentioned above is it actually safe to mark this as exempt?

Comment: Thinking in a general use case, validating inside the view would do the trick... you will have full control about what filters to apply, just inspect the request and request.META to see what you have.

Comment: What if I do not preform any validation accept SSL verification assuming that the certificate that I require is only used by the client's code and not anyone's browser. I will preform further checks but assuming that this was the case I would not have to worry about this would I?

Comment: Only you can define what are your application's risks and only you design your security policies... I have some webservices without csrf validation, because isn't necesary for my "business logic security", other ones have custom validations based on tokens or anything else.